# Preserving and adding new transform on hover (CSS/LESS)

Tags: javascript, css, transform

To make it simple, I have a `div` that I rotate by default with a JS code. But then I want to add a `:hover` class, so that it translates when hovering over it. The problem is, that either the new transform does not apply, or the old is not preserved.

How can I make it work? Btw, I am using LESS, so if there's a solution with LESS, would be happy to hear it.

**P.S.** The angle is being generated according to the number of siblings in JS. Maybe I would be able to do a rotation with LESS and then do a `:hover` there?

```js
document.getElementById("box").style.transform = "rotate(" + 40 + "deg)";
```

```css
#box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}
#box:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  transform: translate(50px) !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">

</div>
```

Comment: That is the way CSS works and Less won't help here. you need to find the existing transform and append the new one to it.

Comment: Here is a suggestion, Instead of modifying the style attribute using JS instead write it to <style> tag using JS. and while you are generating default styles also generate one for hover too, this one will have two transforms one will be same as the normal other will be for hover. So for each element you append two styles to the <style> tag. I hope you understood what I am trying to explain.

Comment: the result should be `transform: translate(50px) rotate(40deg);`, if you only apply `translate` on hover, the other property will be lost.

Comment: @SaqibAmin, yes. Indeed, this is a nice way to make that, and I was thinking about that. But I hoped there was another way to go with LESS.

Comment: @mch, I know, so that was the case.

Comment: @HaykHakobyan That won't be possible using LESS, You have to use JavaScript

Comment: I have created a quick codepen for you, if you want to check that out, i can  put that in answer below

Comment: @SaqibAmin, that would be nice!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS Transform - Keep value on hover state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51283369/css-transform-keep-value-on-hover-state)

Answer (score -1):

you cannot achieve the desired result using CSS/LESS. You have to use JavaScript to generate dynamic styles. A script similar to below can do the task on your hand:

```
var dynamic_styles = '';
var counter = 1;
$('.box').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('data-num', counter);
  dynamic_styles += '.box[data-num="' + counter + '"] {transform: rotate(40deg);}';
  dynamic_styles += '.box[data-num="' + counter + '"]:hover {transform: rotate(40deg) translate(50px);}';
  counter++;
});

$('head').append('<style>' + dynamic_styles + '</style>');
```

Please check the codepen here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGzXEM

P.S. You can change the rotation `40deg` with your dynamically calculated values.

Comment: The problem is, that if something changes on my page, i.e. the number of `box`es, this `<style>` tag will remain.

Comment: You can re-generate the style tag at triggering of such events that may change number of boxes

Comment: This would be complicated. I would rather listen to hover event on each `.box` with JS and adjust `el.style.transform` accordingly.