# CSS Transform - Keep value on hover state

Tags: css, hover, css-transforms

I have transformed a box to rotate 10˚ and added a hover state to increase the size too.

```css
.box {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: blue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    -moz-transform: rotate(10deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(10deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(10deg);
    transform: rotate(10deg);
}
.box:hover {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2) rotate(10deg);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2) rotate(10deg);
    -o-transform: scale(1.2) rotate(10deg);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2) rotate(10deg);
    transform: scale(1.2) rotate(10deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Just for curiosity, I would like to know if there is a way where I don't have to add the 10˚ again on the hover state and it would keep the same value from the static state?
Maybe something similar to this:
.box:hover {transform: scale(1.2) rotate(inherit)}

Comment: `rotate` only accepts `1 parameter, which is an angle value defined in deg, grad, rad or turn (with 1 turn being equivalent to a full circle).`  Also, `inherit` would mean to inherit value from the element's parent, not the element's default state.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not with "standard" CSS currently. Independent/individual transforms [**are coming though**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-2/#individual-transforms).

That said, **CSS variables/custom properties** can assist here.

Simply define the variable as the initial state `scale(1)` and on hover **just change the variable** rather than repeating the whole property set.

```css
.box {
  margin: 3em auto;
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: transform .3s ease;
  --scaler: 1;
  transform: scale(var(--scaler)) rotate(10deg);
}

.box:hover {
  --scaler: 1.2;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```